# Funcionamiento de forms y botones en Razor Page

Tags: razor, .net-core

Amigos, tengo dos botones, el primero selecciona y muestra la informacion en pantalla, y el segundo realiza otro proceso, (envia la informacion a Excel por ejemplo); el asunto es que cuando ejecuto el segundo botón la informacion de pantalla desaparece, las cajas se muestran  en blanco.
Es asi el funcionamiento de Razor Page? tengo que siempre en el segundo submit ver la forma de cargar nuevamente la informacion de mi modelo?
Por favor si me confirman si es asi, o que estoy haciendo mal, o como se debe manejar?.

```
    public class clsPrueba
    {
        [Key]
        public string IdNroservicio { get; set; }
        public string NombreNroServicio { get; set; }
        public string Tarifa { get; set; }
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public clsPrueba Nroservicio { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    public IActionResult OnPostConsulta()
    {
        string suministro = Nroservicio.IdNroservicio;

        Nroservicio.NombreNroServicio = "Nombre Prueba";
        Nroservicio.Tarifa = "Tarifa Prueba";

        return Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnPostExcel()
    {
        string suministro = Nroservicio.IdNroservicio;

        return Page();
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <form method="post">
<input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Nroservicio.IdNroservicio" />
<div >
    <label >Nombre </label>
</div>
<div >
    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Nroservicio.NombreNroServicio" disabled />
</div>
<div >
    <label for="Tarifa" >Tarifa </label>
</div>
<div >
    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Nroservicio.Tarifa" disabled />
</div>
<div>
    <button asp-page-handler="Consulta" type="submit">Consultar</button>
    <button asp-page-handler="Excel" type="submit">Excel</button>
</div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si, tienes que volver a enviar una vista y si fuese necesario los modelos que sirven a esa vista.

Lo que tu describes es el comportamiento natural de la Web, a veces con tanto ajax y frameworks se nos olvida cual es el comportamiento original.

Cuando se hace un submit se envían la información del formulario al servidor y el servidor devuelve "algo", ese algo en su forma natural es otra página. (con el pasar de los años también es muy común que devuelva un JSON).

Hay que recordar que todo el proceso de solicitudes al servidor (POST,GET, PUT, etc) es un proceso sin estado. El servidor no tiene como recordar lo que tú tienes servido en el cliente.

Por otro lado, si lo que deseas es que no recargue la página puedes ocupar AJAX, que se complementa fantástico con .net

*Nota aclaratoria*: En rigor la X de ajax significa XML, y ahora lo común es que sea en JSON, así que posiblemente no sea muy específico seguir llamando a esa técnica como AJAX

*Nota aparte:* Hace varios años Microsoft creó el Web Form, que era la evolución del asp clásico y con el paradigma del Win Form. Esta tecnología manejaba estados, realizaba unos submit que les llamaba postback. Pero la verdad era un lio sobre todo en rendimiento y optaron con MVC que es más limpio y natural

Comment: Ok, gracias Yussef. Falto decir que yo vengo de esos web form :-) de ahi mi costumbre de ver paginas con estados. Tengo un par de paginas en mi intranet, que son recontra antiguas, que me he propuesto actualizarlas a razor page, gracias.